# Using square root to help determine if a number is prime

Tags: java, math, prime-factoring

I'm working on a java homework assignment and part of that assignment is writing a program to find prime numbers. I understand there is a rule that a square root of a number will help determine whether a given number is prime or not. I don't fully understand the concept. Take 37 which is a prime number. If I take the square root of 37 it is 6.0827. So the rule as I understand it is that I don't need to test and divide 37 against any number greater than the square root, which is,  rounded down to 6.

My question is, if you stop at 6, how do you know that your given number is not divisible by 8?  Is my understanding correct in the relationship between prime numbers and their square root or am I missing something?

37 % 2 = (2 * 18 = 36) remainder 1

37 % 3 = (3 * 12 = 36) remainder 1

37 % 4 = (9 * 4 = 36) remainder 1

37 % 5 = ( 7 * 5 = 35) remainder 2

37 % 6 = ( 6 * 6 = 36) remainder 1

Rule says stop at this point. ------------

37 % 7 = ( 7  * 5 = 35 ) remainder 2

37 % 8 = ( 8 * 4 = 32) remainder 5

37 % 9 = (9 * 4 = 36) remainder 1

Comment: It's a good question but it's also a math question, not a programming one; so I'm voting to close as off topic.

Comment: @djechlin it might be a math question, but it's about how a common algorithm works. Would you close vote a question about the Miller-Rabin algorithm? I mean, it's a fairly common algorithm for solving a practical problem. However it requires higher level math like Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum how to implement it? No. Why it works, especially given that it involves higher level math? Yes. The OP is asking why it works, which is great, but off topic.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I was digging around on math.stackexchange for this, I found related questions but am not savvy enough searching there.

Comment: Um, suppose 37 WAS divisible by 8 (which is larger than sqrt(37)), then what is 37/8? Would this number be larger or smaller than sqrt(37)?

Comment: @woodchips I understand the concept now. It is divisible than it would have already been tested. It would be smaller than the square root.

Answer (score 5):

It's Math.

Let's say your number is `x` , and your number `x` is not prime. Then there have to by `m` and `n` such that `mn=x`.

Now, if `m=n=sqrt(x)` we know that `mn=x` indeed, otherwise, at least one of them is *greater* than x, and at least one is *smaller*.

The smaller one, *has* to be smaller than the root (otherwise we'd be multiplying two larger than root numbers), so your algorithm will hit it first.

Comment: in every case without exception no matter how big the number?

Comment: @JessicaM. did you follow Benjamin's logic?

Comment: @JessicaM. You can obtain composite numbers by multiplying two numbers, if both of them are bigger than the root than the result also is, so one of them _has_ to be smaller. That's because both are at least as big (let's say one is `sqrt(x)+k` and the other `sqrt(x)+j` we get `(sqrt(x)+k)(sqrt(x)+j) = x+sqrt(x)(j+k)+kj` which is bigger than `x`.

Comment: @djechlin I'm thinking about it right now.

Comment: @JessicaM. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes i did. Thanks for you help. It was hard for me to grasp the concept at first but after i did a couple of examples the concept made more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at a *non*-prime number to illustrate.

```
36 / 1 =    36
36 / 2 =    18
36 / 3 =    12
36 / 4 =     9
36 / 6 =     6
```

Notice that as the numbers on the left go up, those on the right go down.  (I wrote them in order, starting with the smallest factors.) When they run into each other (6 and 6) we're at the square root.  I wrote them in order, starting with the smallest factors.

Remember that factors come in *pairs*. If were to continue past this point, I'd just repeat the same pairs again:

```
36 /  9 =    4
36 / 12 =    3
36 / 18 =    2
36 / 36 =    1
```

So by searching up to the square root, I've already found all (pairs of) factors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try squaring integers starting from 1 and checking if the square is equal to the the possible prime number (let's call it `n`), until the square is bigger than `n`?

Comment: a.k.a. the number is bigger than the square root of n.